# Writing an asynchronous api in clojure – ok to use a channel for a single put/take?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure

I'm learning clojure and as part of that process I would like to write a library with an asynchronous api. I see that there are alot of options like `future`, callbacks, `core.async`. I was thinking about building the api on top of `core.async` so I might have something like:

```
;service
(defn load 
  (def c (chan))
  (go 
     ;do some stuff...
     (>! c result)
  )
  c
)

;client 

(def result (<!! (service/load)))
```

My question is – I'd be creating and returning a channel for every method invocation, once the result has been taken I've no need for it. Is this a valid/normal way to use `core.async`. Alot of the documentation I've read seems to imply that a channel would be typically used to put more than just one payload.

If not what are the alternatives for writing an asynchronous api. I looked at `future` and `promise` but I don't like the idea of blocking when trying to access the value within. Ideally I'd like to use a pattern similar to [scala's `Future`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) where you can call `future.map{ r => //do something }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only single "puts" and "takes", I'd strongly recommend to use dedicated future/promise library for that. Take a look at [`manifold`](https://github.com/ztellman/manifold/) or [`promesa`](https://github.com/funcool/promesa).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at those and they looked interesting, I guess I was trying to keep the dependencies as standard as possible, so `core.async` seemed preferable. I was planning on using aleph for the http server.

Answer (score 1):

I've settled on the position that:

- it's fine to use channels
- `go` returns a channel, so no need to create one and then call `put` inside the `go` body.

The example can be cleand up to look like:

```
;service
(defn load 
  (go 
    ;do some stuff...
    result))

;client 

(def result (<!! (service/load)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would define your channel once, outside the functions that use it. Maybe this code is more like what you are looking for:

```
(def c (chan))

;service
(defn load [] 
  (go 
    (loop [x 0] 
      (>! c x) 
      (Thread/sleep 1000) 
      (recur (inc x)))))

; client
(loop [] 
  (println (<!! c)) 
  (recur))
```

The `go` block runs in a different thread. It looks like in your case you want this thread to be producing stuff to be consumed by the main thread. It might make more sense to have the main thread producing and the go block consuming, but of course, this depends on your application.

Regarding `future` and `promise`, you can use `realized?` to test whether they have been fulfilled. However you should try to design your application to avoid such polling.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I was thinking of skipping `future`, `promise` because you either have to call `realized?` as you wait, or block while you dereference. The issue I see with the above would be if 2 client requests come in they'll both be taking from the same channel so that could lead to unexpected results?

Comment: It's a common pattern to have multiple consumers taking from the same channel. I'm not clear what you mean by an asynchronous API. Could you give an example use case?

Comment: I can't give a concrete use case (still figuring out the requirements) - but [this gist](https://gist.github.com/edeustace/e30efa6d9fa6732e6e7bca8dc489a1e6) is trying to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Channels are reasonably cheap, so it's fine if you want to make one and only use it for a single value. However, your reasoning of not wanting to block on a promise or future doesn't make much sense to me since you're blocking on the channel when you call `<!!`.

Another note: Using `def` inside of a `defn` is not the way to declare local variables, you should instead use `let`. So your code becomes:

```
(defn load 
  (let [c (chan)]
    (go 
       ;do some stuff...
       (>! c result))
    c))
```

Comment: Hi, I was only blocking as part of the example, the plan would be to use a non blocking take at the end of the line. Cheers.

Comment: In that case, and looking at your example, I would say that creating a new channel at the start of the function makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your `load` function is used only from one context then using the channel style is fine.

However, returning channels encourages the use of `go` blocks, and `go` blocks proliferate. You can break apart your `load` function as follows:

```
(defn load [callback]
  (go 
    ; do some stuff...
    (callback result)))

(defn load< []
  (let [c (chan)]
    (load #(if (nil? %) (close! c) (put! c %)))))
```

The first function uses a callback function to notify the caller of the result. The second function wraps the result from the first in a channel. `load` can be used without `core.async`. This approach and a useful function for lifting regular asynchronous functions written in the callback style into `core.async`'s channel style is described in http://www.lispcast.com/core-async-code-style.